# Is it necessary to make a for loop to make matricies of ones based on a matrix of dimensions?

Tags: matlab

I would like to generate a set of all 1 matrices given a matrix of sizes, (`dimensions` in this example), but I have been having a hard time making the dimensions matrix return a size vector that `ones` can work with.

My first instinct is: `dimensions(:,:)`

I read this (incorrectly) as `return a matrix of size vectors [x,y]`

But this doesn't seem to work -- Is there any way to use dimensions to produce a matrix of size vectors?

I am tempted to use a loop to iterate, for i = 1 to 3 `dimensions(i,:)` , but I was wondering if this is the only way.

Code:

```
clear;

%3x2
dimensions = [32,40; %32x40 box of ones
          20, 30; %20x30 box of ones
          60, 10; %60x10 box of ones
          ];



Onesboxes = ones(dimensions(1,:));

%this works, but I really want OnesBoxes to be an array such that:

%OnesBoxes(1) = 32x40 box of ones
%OnesBoxes(2) = 20x30 box of ones
%OnesBoxes(3) = 60x10 box of ones

% if I try:
OnesBoxes = ones(dimensions); 

%Error using ones: Size vector should be a row vector with real elements.

%what I want to do is pass in sizes as rows in dimensions

%passing in the size of the ones array as a single vector works:
%onessize dimensions: 1x2
onessize = [4,2];

%tTestOnes dimensions: 4x2
tTestOnes = ones(onessize);

%making dimensions a 2x3 matrix instead doesn't seem to make a difference
%(I was thinking that maybe matlab thinks of matricies as an array of
%columns instead of arrays of rows?)
    %dimensions2 = [32,20,60; 40,30,10];

    %tOnesBoxes2 = ones(dimensions2);
```

EDIT: Outputs:

Output of

```
onessize = [4,2];

%tTestOnes dimensions: 4x2
tTestOnes = ones(onessize);
```

is a 4x2 array of all ones

Output of

```
dimensions = [32,40; %32x40 box of ones
          20, 30; %20x30 box of ones
          60, 10; %60x10 box of ones
          ];

Onesboxes = ones(dimensions(1,:));
```

Is a 32x40 array of all ones

Output of

```
dimensions = [32,40; %32x40 box of ones
              20, 30; %20x30 box of ones
              60, 10; %60x10 box of ones
              ];
OnesBoxes = ones(dimensions);
```

Is an error

> Error using ones Size vector should be a row vector with real
>   elements.

Comment: Can you give an example with exact input and ouput?

Comment: Added outputs -- sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by inputs, the dimensions array is what specifies the size of the ones arrays

Comment: Luis, I was going to comment on your answer: This looks like about what I'm looking for, though could you explain why it's necessary to pass `ones` cells, as opposed to passing `ones` rows in `dimensions`? It seems like cells have a more strict grouping, whereas maybe `ones` was misinterpreting my 3x2 `dimensions` matrix before? FWIW in my opinion that was a helpful answer, why did you delete it?

Comment: I deleted it because after writing it I saw the other, earlier answer, was very similar (only with an explicit `for` loop instead of `cellfun`). You need to pass `ones` vectors that define the matrix size. If you want several matrices, you need to call `ones` several times. To collect all resulting matrices you need a cell array because the matrices have different sizes. My answer didn't pass `ones` cells. It passed vectors. I used cells as an intermediate step to split the input and to bee able to use `cellfun`. But it's the same ideas as Praveen's answer

Comment: `If you want several matrices, you need to call ones several times` this is what I'm looking for -- ones can only make a single matrix per call. Also `To collect all resulting matrices you need a cell array because the matrices have different sizes` answers my other question about the limitations of `:` -- if you put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Done. I've undeleted my answer and added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass [`ones`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) a *vector* that defines the matrix size. If you want several matrices, you need to call `ones` several times. To collect all resulting matrices you need a cell array because the matrices have different sizes.

You can do that using a `for` loop, or `arrayfun`, or [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). Here I'm using the latter:

```
dimensions = [ 2 3;
               4 5 ]; %// input data. Each row defines a matrix size
dimCell = mat2cell(dimensions, ones(1,size(dimensions,1)), size(dimensions,2));
    %// split each row into a cell, ready to be used as input for `cellfun`
result = cellfun(@(x) ones(x), dimCell, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

This gives a cell array of the desired matrices. In the example,

```
>>  result
result = 
    [2x3 double]
    [4x5 double]
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
result{2} =
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with having a for loop, the simplest way I can think of is:

```
dimensions = [32,40; %32x40 box of ones
              20, 30; %20x30 box of ones
              60, 10; %60x10 box of ones
             ];
for i=1:size(dimensions,1)
    OnesBoxes{i}=ones(dimensions(i,:));
end
```

This will create `OnesBoxes` like how you wanted like this:

```
OnesBoxes{1}% = 32x40 box of ones
OnesBoxes{2}% = 20x30 box of ones
OnesBoxes{3}% = 60x10 box of ones
```

Comment: There's a slight error in your code, note that `%60x10 box of ones];` causes the closing square bracket to be commented out. Aside from that, I like the idea of putting sub matrices in cells, though I'm still curious if there's a way to do this with just the : operator and `dimensions`.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it. Also, changed `OnesBoxes(1)` to `OnesBoxes{1}` etc. Choose whichever suits your need.
Regarding your question of using `:` operator alone, I don't think you can do it without iterating either through a for loop or the `cellfun` as in @LuisMendo 's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm more than a little perplexed as to the limitations of the : operator in Matlab, I can't quite visualize what it does, I think you're right that it can't be done, but I'm not sure as to why -- I'll probably bump into this limitation again in this application, if it would be possible to maybe explain why this data structure setup doesn't work, that would really help me out. Right now the only thing I can come up with is "I'm confusing the : operator", as in it doesn't _know_ to make a matrix of matrices.

Comment: [This post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/) explains all about the colon operator in Matlab. It might help you get a clear understanding of the uses and usage of the colon operator in Matlab. In short, the `:` operator is used for array indexing. To **create** matrix of matrices, you need more than just the `:` operator. As already mentioned, to create more than one matrix, you need to call the function `ones` more than once.